# how send multiple files using header

Tags: php, html, file, header

How to send multiple files using header() or maybe smth else, for example '.doc' file and '.xls' file?

Without refreshing the browser.

Comment: are you talking about for mail function header ?

Comment: What do you want to do? What have you tried? If you want to load something in a document without refreshing, you'll need AJAX. You can use multiple requests then.

Comment: Elaborate on your question and make it clearer, hopefully without using words such as "smth".

Comment: However, if you want to download multiple files at once, that isn't possible. You can only download one file at a time.

Comment: @looper why do you think it's not possible? Of course it is to download multiple files in parallel (the downloads do finish at different moments and they always use different TCP channels, though).

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: Mrhm. I meant in one request. I would edit it, but I can't.

Comment: Befor, I made only an Excel report (Pear excel writer), using POST data. It worked fine, in a result i had .xls file in my downloads. Now i have to send two files: Excel and Word, attached to this Excel doc, composed on the same POST data. I want to do it in a one click, without any ajax here, in other words i need only serverside solution.

Comment: Then I suggest you use `.zip`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. It's not a PHP limitation, it's an HTTP/Web-Browser limitation. HTTP doesn't provide a mechanism for sending multiple files over one request.

You could, however, have some PHP script that generates multiple iframes, which would initiate one download each, and fake it that way.